# Opening the GUI Designer in MonoDevelop

Tags: user-interface, interface, monodevelop, designer

I have just installed MonoDevelop 2.0 on Windows and created a New GTK Project.

I can't seem to find any way to open the GUI Designer (there are no 'Source Code' and 'Design' tabs under the codument either).

How do I open/use the GUI Designer in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 4):

I recently installed MonoDevelop 3.0.6 and ran into this problem as well.  I created a new solution, selected VBNet and Gtk# 2.0 Project.  I then opened the MyWindow.vb file and there was no tabs at the bottom for selecting Souce Code or Design.  Also the Toolbox was empty.

I then tried creating a solution using C# and GtK# and when I opened MainWindow.cs the Designer tab and Source tabs show up at the bottom of the window.  Here are the instructions for it's use http://monodevelop.com/Stetic_GUI_Designer.

Update: As per the Bugzilla Bug 10986, GTK# Designer only works with C# Projects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create a **GTK+ Project** which allows you to use the GUI designer. After doing this, user interface references will be automatically loaded and a skeleton MainWindow code file will be automatically generated by the IDE itself. If you click on this **MainWindow** code file from the solution pad, **'Source'** and **'Designer'** tabs will appear at the bottom. Finally, just click on **Designer** tab and now you can see your application main window and GTK+ widgets in the toolbox.